# Position:absolute not working unless giving a border

Tags: html, css, position, keyframe

I have a keyframe animation in html5 and css3.
I need a blinking effect, so i coded css3 keyframe animation according to that. My problem is that I gave a 'position:absolute' for a div. It won't work unless I put an additional code for border 1px, If i give

> border:1px solid transparent
>   the 'position:absolute' will work, else it won't

I don't need that border because it will cause width issue in my design.

This is my html

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes blink {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes blink {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes blink {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    .img-front {
      -webkit-animation: blink 1s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -moz-animation: blink 1s;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -o-animation: blink 1s;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      position: inherit;
      left: 0;
    }
    .img-back {
      position: inherit;
      left: 0;
      width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img class="img-back" src="http://goo.gl/L7WKNE" />
  <img class="img-front" src="http://goo.gl/EBMULc" />
</body>

</html>
```

How can I sort it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: that 'width' issue - surely that can be sorted using the **calc()** css?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to put your images in an div and then use position absolute. The will work fir sure.

```
<div class='img1'>
<img class="img-back" src="2668.jpg" />
</div>

<div class='img2'>
<img class="img-front" src="2668.png" />
</div>
```

use this css

```
.img1,.img2{position:absolute; margin-left:0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes blink {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes blink {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes blink {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    .img-front {
      -webkit-animation: blink 1s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -moz-animation: blink 1s;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -o-animation: blink 1s;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      position: inherit;
      left: 0;
    }
    .img-back {
      position: inherit;
      left: 0;
      width: 500px;
    }
   .img-wrapper{
     position: absolute;
     float: left;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="img-back" src="http://goo.gl/L7WKNE" />
      <img class="img-front" src="http://goo.gl/EBMULc" />
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IF i am not wrong on as per your requirement, You can apply float:left with position:absolute to the div.